# Chrome advance REST client overwrites Content Type

Tags: rest, content-type

I am trying to test binary files payload through chrome advance rest client.

Even though I enter content type as the following:

> Content-Type: application/octet-stream

The REST client replaces it with something like this:

> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarylUWv5yh2017BFObW

This causes my API to barf, as it does not support multipart/form-data content type.

I looked around on the net & found a reference to this, but nothing else useful.
http://code.google.com/p/chrome-rest-client/issues/detail?id=212

Is there a way to use application/octet-stream content type.

Comment: It's very hard to place this question on Stack Overflow. [tag:rest-client] is not applicable (different client), [tag:google-chrome-extension] is about **developing** extensions, which does not apply. Maybe it's time for a tag for Advanced REST Client itself - it's [over 300 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=advanced+rest+client+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: But probably it's best if you look for support in the right place - the bug tracker and Chrome extension support requests in the store listing itself.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Xan. I struggled with finding the right tags for this too. I did look at all the issues reported, but I was hoping that someone in SO would have a workaround. This seems like a pretty major hindrance to using the Advanced REST Client.